# JavaScript regular expressions - match a series of hexadecimal numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Greetings JavaScript and regular expression gurus,

I want to return all matches in an input string that are 6-digit hexadecimal numbers with any amount of white space in between.  For example, "333333 e1e1e1 f4f435" should return an array:

```
array[0] = 333333  
array[1] = e1e1e1  
array[2] = f4f435
```

Here is what I have, but it isn't quite right-- I'm not clear how to get the optional white space in there, and I'm only getting one match.

> colorValuesArray = colorValues.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/);

Thanks for your help,

-NorthK

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the *g* flag to match globally:

```
/[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g
```

Another good enhancement would be adding word boundaries:

```
/\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}\b/g
```

If you like you could also set the *i* flag for case insensitive matching:

```
/\b[0-9A-F]{6}\b/gi
```

Comment: Though, this does allow _any_ characters between the numbers, not just whitespace.

Comment: Hmmm, I think any allowing any characters between matches is OK in this case; thanks bdukes.

Comment: @bdukes: Word boundaries require a change from word characters (`\w`) to non-word characters (`\W`) or vice versa or the start or the end of the string. So the character before and after our `[0-9A-F]{6}` must be non-word characters or the start or end of the string.

Comment: The characters before and after any 6-digit number must be a non-word character, but you can have other nonsense inbetween, like  `"333333   X e1e1e1 f4f435"`

Comment: @bdukes: Sure, but the `X` wouldn’t be matched.

Comment: @Gumbo: exactly, just saying that it allows extra characters between the numbers, so this wouldn't be a solution if only whitespace were allowed between the numbers.

Comment: So, `\x` and `[:xdigit:]` aren't avaiable for JS?

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively to the answer above, a more direct approach might be:

`/\p{Hex_Digit}{6}/ug`

You can read more about Unicode Properties [here](https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode#unicode-properties-p).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the situation, but I *usually* want to make sure my code can't silently accept (and ignore, or misinterpret) incorrect input. So I would normally do something like this.

```
var arr = s.split();
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!arr[i].match(/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$/)
        throw new Error("unexpected junk in string: " + arr[i]);
    arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i], 16);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason.
in this case I think it's OK 'cause the user will immediately see the results graphically of what they typed in if they typed in garbage :)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
colorValues.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g);
```

Note the `g` flag to Globally match.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = subject.match(/\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}\b/g);
```

gives you an array of all 6-digit hexadecimal numbers in the given string `subject`.

The `\b` word boundaries are necessary to avoid matching parts of longer hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are looking for hex color with alpha code, the following regex works:

```
/\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,2}\b\g
```

The code allows both hex with or without the alpha code.