# How to restrict a textbox only to enter a hexadecimal value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox in my HTML form, and I would like to restrict a user to enter a hexadecimal value in it between 0 and f. How can I do it?

My HTML textbox code:

```
<div class="input-resp-hpux-vbus"><span><input  class="textbox" id="vbus-id" name="vbus-id" type="text" size="5" maxlength="3"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['vbus-id'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['vbus-id']); }?>" /></span></div>
```

Comment: try this regex `(0-9[A-F])+`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript regular expressions - match a series of hexadecimal numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156746/javascript-regular-expressions-match-a-series-of-hexadecimal-numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and validate it before submit or after keypress:

*[Regular expression to validate hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287684/regular-expression-to-validate-hex-string)*

```
var control = document.getElementById('vbus-id')';
var regExp = new RegExp(/^0x[0-9A-F]{1,4}$/i);
if (!regExp.test(control))
   alert('invalid');
```

Comment: I tried this with onkeyup function. but not giving any alert warning

Comment: I have tried with `$('#vbus-id').bind('keyup', function() { 
var control = document.getElementById('vbus-id');
if (!control.test(/^([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){8,9}$/));
   alert('invalid');
} );'

Comment: sorry @acr, the last update was wrong. Now is correct

Comment: correction plz:- if(!regExp.test(control) to if(!regExp.test(control)), first brace end missing at if condition

Comment: Thnx @SharifHridoyKhan. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/zXbHz/,

```
<div class="input-resp-hpux-vbus"><span><input  class="textbox" id="vbus-id" name="vbus-id" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" onblur="isValidhex(this)"  value="" /></span></div>

function isValidhex(ele) {
     var isOk  =  /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(ele.value);
    return (isOk)?ele.value ="" :true ;
}
```

Comment: Why do people use *match* when *test* is the obvious choice? `/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i.test(s)`, which returns a boolean value with no need for a test or conversion. If you **really** want to use *match*, consider `!!str.match(/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i)`. Oh, and a valid hex colour value can have 3 or 6 digits. :-)

Comment: I am able enter any values in the jsfiddle.

Comment: I have resetted input value to null with this line in the function **ele.value =""** . Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zXbHz/1/

Comment: No Change..try to enter a value other than 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f in this fiddle and check..

Comment: I am looking for a onkeyup function for this (before a form submit)

Comment: @acr I can able to type other characters and i dont know why you don't. **onblur="isValidhex(this)"** this to **onkeyup="isValidhex(this)"** in the input element.

Comment: Not sure whether you understand my question. I want user only enter hex values from 0 to f. In your code, if it is allowed value, it should alert. correct ? but i dont see any difference . I have changed onblur to onkeyup